# Match IDs in a column (comma delimited string of IDs per cell) to another sheet, pull the relevant values over & apply hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help with an Excel macro-- I'm currently struggling to write a macro that combines all three processes. I have two sheets: Sheet 1 contains a column with multiple IDs in each cell delimited by commas (can go up to like 30 IDs in one cell), Sheet 2 contains data for each of the IDs.

Here's the sequence that I'm trying to achieve:

1. De-concatenate IDs in Sheet 1 into separate cells
2. Match each of the de-concatenated IDs to its row in Sheet 2, copy over and add values from column 6 and 7 to Sheet 1's respective cell.
3. Apply a hyperlink to the final cell.

For example, here's what a row in Sheet 1 & 2 currently look like:

Sheet 1

| ID |
| --- |
| 123456, 789123 |

Sheet 2

| ID | Status | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | In Progress | A |
| 789123 | Done | B |

And here's what I'd like the output to look for Sheet 1 when the macro runs:

| ID |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456, 789123 | [123456, In Progress, A](https://stackoverflow.com/) | [789123, Done, B](https://stackoverflow.com/) |

My code is super off, but here's what I have:

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim sel As Range
Set sel = Selection
Dim arr() As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set wsCheck = wb.Sheets("2")

 'Column N (IDs)
wb.Sheets("1").Columns("N:N").Select
For Each cell In sel
    arr = Split(cell, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        m = Application.Match("*" & arr(i) & "*", wsCheck.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                cell.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = wsCheck.Cells(m, 6).Value & wsCheck.Cells(m, 7).Value
                cell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell.Offset(0, i + 1), Address:="URL" & arr(i), TextToDisplay:=arr(i)
            End If
          
    Next i
Next cell
```

Comment: What is happening (or not happening) when you run your code which is different from what you want/expect?

Comment: @TimWilliams The macro runs without error but nothing happens aside from the selection of column N as far as I can tell. When I take out the matching part, leaving only the de-concatenation + adding of hyperlinks, the output is as expected. It's mostly the matching process I am struggling to get working.

Comment: `m = Application.Match(CLng(arr(i)), wsCheck.Columns(1), 0)` or do you really need partial matching?  That "*" wildcard from your previous post was for searching for one value inside a list of values in a cell, so it needed the wildcards - here you can do an exact search.

Comment: @TimWilliams No the IDs should match exactly, so no real need. But even without, it still won't produce the necessary output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook, arr, ws As Worksheet, wsCheck As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long, v, m
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("1")
    Set wsCheck = wb.Sheets("2")
    
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub 'make sure a range is selected
    If Selection.Worksheet.Name <> ws.Name Then Exit Sub '...on the correct sheet
    
    For Each cell In Selection.EntireRow.Columns("N").Cells
        arr = Split(cell.Value, ",")
    
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            v = CLng(Trim(arr(i))) 'remove spaces and convert to number
            m = Application.Match(v, wsCheck.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                With cell.Offset(0, i + 1)
                    .Value = Join(Array(v, wsCheck.Cells(m, 6).Value, _
                                        wsCheck.Cells(m, 7).Value), ",")
                    .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1), _
                       Address:="", _
                       SubAddress:=wsCheck.Cells(m, 1).Address(0, 0, xlA1, True), _
                       TextToDisplay:=.Value
                End With
            End If
              
        Next i
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, this does seem to work but only performs for the last row for some reason?

Comment: My working copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19wW164E4JDZdCmU_n9lzExtvUrKc9QLC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106591725375141807281&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Sure thing, I made a dummy file here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RglBg9DOb-cWift-QVEWEKEepD2RjSdY/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115510911352849014794&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Did notice that if I manually selected the cells in column N, it does loop through as expected however?

Comment: It should not matter whether you directly select cells in ColN - that's the purpose of  `For Each cell In sel.EntireRow.Columns("N").Cells` - even if you select cells in (eg) col D it will still look at Col N...

Comment: Yes that's what I expected, if you take a look at the Dummy file it isn't pointing correctly, which is strange to me. Though manual selection does work.

Comment: Can you explain exactly, using an example from your "Dummy" workbook, how it's not working as you expect?

Comment: If you press run for the test macro in the Dummy workbook it doesn't execute unless you manually select the N column. Suggests that the selection part of the macro isn't functioning though I can't quite figure out why... it looks correct to me.

Comment: Works for me - if I select (eg) I2:I6 on Sheet2  and run `test` then columns O:Q get populated with the results from values in N2:N6

Comment: Ah figured it out-- my issue was that I didn't want to manually select at all (regardless of in column I or N). Wanted to run it straight even if I was just in a single random cell on the sheet-- fixed it now! Just added a line to select the UsedRange minus header for me, thanks for the help! Works perfectly now.